# Is it non-conformant to use a DTD only for the purpose of defining entities?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, validation, xsd, dtd

I created an XML file that makes use of entities defined in a .dtd file for the purposes of abbreviating repetitive content. The file also references an XSD file which is used for validation. The .dtd file is not used for validation, and it contains no content aside from `<!ENTITY ...>` declarations and comments.

MS Visual Studio accepts this arrangement and does not flag any errors. (I have tested that the XSD is indeed being used for validation by temporarily perturbing the content of the XML file and observing that the expected validation errors arise.) However, I was curious as to whether this arrangement is strictly conformant with how DTD files are supposed to work, so I tried submitting the 3 files to a web-based validator. The web-based validator spat out a list of 2,000 or so errors which were all of the form 'Element type "ElementName" must be declared'. This suggests to me that it expected the DTD file to contain additional content, serving the purposes of validation.

The observed behaviour of Visual Studio is useful to me, but is it technically deviating from the relevant standards here?

The first few lines of the XML file are of the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE FooCollection SYSTEM "entities.dtd">

<FooCollection
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FooCollection.xsd">
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file is *well-formed* but not *valid*. That's perfectly OK (and *conformant*). If you ask the XML parser to do validity checking, it will give errors, but if you ask it only to do well-formedness checking, it won't.